# Powershell: does ps4.0 has "using namespace" semantics or its equivalence?

Tags: powershell, namespaces, using

I find it not possible to use using namespace in powershell 4.0?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write full namespaces to use a class within. Say `[System.IO.File]`. Or you can omit `System`, but not anything else. Or you can use a variable as in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/74744/using-namespaces-in-powershell) to save you typing and compute the fully qualified class name at runtime:

```
$ns="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates"
$store = New-Object "$ns.X509Store"(StoreName,StoreLocation)
```

There is no "using namespace" in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

PS 4 doesn't have `using <namespace>`.  There was limited support for `using <namespace>` in PS v5 preview builds.  It worked in regular scripts but not modules in builds from June.  I haven't checked lately to see if the limited support is still in v5.